# Why can't I access a Python module?

Tags: python, import

I have the following structure:

```
project
├── sum_package
│   └── sum_module.py
├── testing.py
```

I try to access `sum_module.py` from `testing.py` in two different ways:

First:

```
from sum_package import sum_module
sum_module.great_summation(1,2)
```

Second:

```
import sum_package
sum_package.sum_module.great_summation(1,2)
```

First works, second doesn't:

```
AttributeError: module 'sum_package' has no attribute 'sum_module'
```

Can someone explain why?

EDIT: tried adding `__init__.py` into either/both the package folder / the project folder, does not help.

EDIT 2: so it seems like the problem is $PYTHONPATH. I've tried adding my src (project) directory as PYTHONPATH, like this:

```
export PYTHONPATH = "$PWD"
```

while in src, but I still get the same error. What else am I missing?:)

Comment: Whats the contents of your init.py in the sum_package folder?

Comment: All the __init__ files are empty

Answer (score 0):

```
project
├── __init__.py
|
├── sum_package
    ├── __init__.py
    |
│   └── sum_module.py
├── testing.py
```

The `__init__.py` files are required to make python treat directories containing the file as `packages`. Make your folder structure like this.  In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file. 
Then try

**testing.py**

```
from sum_package import sum_module

sum_module.great_summation(1,2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I tried adding both __init__.py and get the same error. My impression was that since 3.3. __init__.py were not necessary?

"Allowing implicit namespace packages means that the requirement to provide an __init__.py file can be dropped completely, and affected portions can be installed into a common directory or split across multiple directories as distributions see fit."

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/